# Random "None" console print occurs

Tags: python

I am currently working on a twitter bot and have to check if ID's match or not.
My following method does exactly this, but it always returns None on console and I don't get why it's returning "None".

```
def check_for_new_tweet(tweet_id, tweets):
    if path.exists("id_file"):
        f = open("id_file", "r+")
        id = f.read()

    else:
        f = open("id_file", "r+")
        f.write(tweet_id)

    if tweet_id != id:
        matches = check_if_contains(words_to_check, tweets)
        with open("id_file", "r+") as f:
            f.write(tweet_id)
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
        return matches
```

Comment: well if `tweet_id != id` then you aren't returning anything, so the function will instead return `None` - another situation is when the function `check_if_contains(..)` returns `None`

Comment: @oskros  wow, well I guess I am the dumbest person alive. thanks a lot, I just stared on the code for an eternity and didn't get what's wrong

Comment: what's weird is tho, even if it finds a match it still returns the match and None aswell

Comment: so you didn't post the code for your `check_if_contains` function - maybe that is returning `None`..